# ProgrammingError: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "iris_category"

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8

I have created a module and am adding a category, it was working correct in previous version of Odoo and on 10-april-2015 i updated new version i am getting the error 
ERROR:

```
 HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "iris_business_category__category_id".
```

, in query  SELECT

```
"iris_business_category"."id",iris_category__content_id."title" FROM "iris_business_category","iris_category" as "iris_business_category__category_id","iris_content" as "iris_category__content_id"
                    WHERE "iris_business_category".id IN %s AND ("iris_business_category"."category_id" = "iris_business_category__category_id"."id") AND ("iris_category"."content_id" = "iris_category__content_id"."id")  ORDER BY "iris_business_category"."id"
```

How to solve this issue in new version??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is a problem and it has been mentioned on odoo.